# What does it mean when draft trainings are Not Learned in Bixby Studio?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I don't understand how to force these draft trainings to be learned. The Comple NL Model button is greyed out and I don't see anything else I can do.  Are they waiting for something to happen on the Bixby server side?

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

When a training example is not learned, the NL model needs to be compiled. In your case, please try restarting the IDE to get out of the current state where your examples are not learned but you cannot compile the NL model either.

If it continues to occur after a restart, please file a support ticket via the IDE's Help dropdown menu to allow the team to investigate further.